# how rotate text?

Tags: css

how can i rotate text 90 degree which be supported in both FF and IE(6,7,8) ?

Comment: @person who is trying to close this .. **how** is this off topic?

Comment: Please direct CSS design questions to [Doctype](http://doctype.com/).

Comment: Belongs on Webmasters or Doctype.

Comment: if this is off topic, are all the css questions ever asked off topic? there are 20,000+ of them. If so, why don't you go on a crusade to close all of them?

Comment: @John Gietzen - if css questions annoy you, why dont you set it to your ignored tags and leave them be?

Comment: Actually, I don't think all CSS questions are off-topic. According to the FAQ, the relevant section says "If your question is about ... Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is 'designer', ask on Doctype". So it looks like if you consider yourself a programmer, the question is okay here. If you consider yourself a designer, go to Doctype. And I think this self-analyzed decision is important. The communities are different, so you will likely get more technical, programmer-oriented answers here. And maybe that's what you want.

Comment: @meder:  CSS questions don't annoy me.  However, CSS questions that only pertain to *style* are not programming related.

Comment: @all of the above friends:I deal with this question when i was working on a jquery project.I ask my css question here because i saw css tag and many questions in this field here.i don't know it is better to ask somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-moz-transform:rotate(-270deg); 
-moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
-o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
-o-transform-origin:  bottom left;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

Here's a link to read: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation) on how to do it to support all the modern browsers

More articles here:

- [Real text rotation with CSS](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css)
- [CSS Rotate Text 90 Degrees](http://codebasic.net/css-rotate-text-90-degrees/)